# How does keras.evaluate() calculate the loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am building a MLP using TensorFlow 2.0. I am plotting the learning curve and also using keras.evaluate on both training and test data to see how well it performed. The code I'm using:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, 
                    epochs=200, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
eval_result_tr = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
eval_result_te = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("[training loss, training accuracy]:", eval_result_tr)
print("[test loss, test accuracy]:", eval_result_te)
#[training loss, training accuracy]: [0.5734676122665405, 0.9770742654800415]
#[test loss, test accuracy]: [0.7273344397544861, 0.9563318490982056]


#plot the learning rate curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history["loss"], label='eğitim')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='doğrulama')
plt.xlabel("Öğrenme ivmesi")
plt.ylabel("Hata payı")
plt.title("Temel modelin öğrenme eğrisi")
plt.legend()
```

The output is:

[image: The output:]

My question is: How keras.evaluate() calculates the training loss to be 0.5734676122665405? I take the average of `history.history["loss"]` bu it returns different (0.7975356701016426) value.

Or, am I mistaken to begin with by trying to evaluate the model performance on training data by `eval_result_tr = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)`?

Comment: Regularization techniques like dropout are usually only active during training. That could be one of the reasons for the differences.

Comment: This has been asked many times before, the loss you see is with changing weights during training, evaluating outside of training will use fixed weights, so you will always see a different loss value. Please search the site before asking.

Comment: I actually searched the site and found similar posts but were not exactly the same issue) and none of them clarify the answer as you did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For community benefit, adding **@Dr. Snoopy's** answer here in the `answer section`.

> This has been asked many times before, the loss you see is with
> changing weights during training, evaluating outside of training will
> use fixed weights, so you will always see a different loss value.